# App will not allow me to edit other people's posts

Tags: bug, android-app

On stackoverflow.com I can edit a post and it goes into a queue for approval. The Android app let's me do the edit and then says 'this account is not allowed to edit'. Either it should allow me to edit or it should not. I like the look and feel of the app.